# How to add specific values from a table to a list

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code taking variables from a table and adds to a list if there is a variable, or adds None value if there is not. I defined those variables with "obj" and with a for loop put them into my list with the following code:

```
catalog=[]

rad1='0.001s'
rad2='0.01s'
rad3='0.1s'
rad4='1s'
rad5='10s'


for i in range(len(RA)):
        result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad1)
        if result_table is None:
            result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad2)
            if result_table is None:
                result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad3)
                if result_table is None:
                    result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad4)
                    if result_table is None:
                        result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad5)
        if result_table is None:
            catalog.append([i,None,None])
        else:
            for obj in result_table:
                catalog.append([i,obj[0],RA[i],DEC[i],obj[1],obj[2],obj[4] if obj[12]!='--' else None,obj[12] if obj[12]!='--' else None,obj[13] if obj[13]!='--' else None,obj[14] if obj[14]!='--' else None,obj[15] if obj[15]!='--' else None,obj[16] if obj[16]!='--' else None,obj[17] if obj[17]!='--' else None,obj[18] if obj[18]!='--' else None,obj[19] if obj[19]!='--' else None,obj[20] if obj[20]!='--' else None,obj[21] if obj[21]!='--' else None,obj[22] if obj[22]!='--' else None,obj[23] if obj[23]!='--' else None])
```

Here the second object, obj[0], is names from table. I want to not add them if its last letter is b,c,d,e,f,g or h.

So basically i want to take values expect their last letter is b,c,d,e,f,g,h. How can i code that?

Answer (score 0):

See this code :

```
catalog=[]

rad1='0.001s'
rad2='0.01s'
rad3='0.1s'
rad4='1s'
rad5='10s'
exception_list = [ 'b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h']

for i in range(len(RA)):
        result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad1)
        if result_table is None:
            result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad2)
            if result_table is None:
                result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad3)
                if result_table is None:
                    result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad4)
                    if result_table is None:
                        result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius= rad5)
        if result_table is None:
            catalog.append([i,None,None])
        else:
            for obj in result_table:
                if not obj[0][len(obj[0])-1:] in exception_list :
                    new_obj = obj[0]
                else :
                    new_obj = None
                catalog.append([i,new_obj,RA[i],DEC[i],obj[1],obj[2],obj[4] if obj[12]!='--' else None,obj[12] if obj[12]!='--' else None,obj[13] if obj[13]!='--' else None,obj[14] if obj[14]!='--' else None,obj[15] if obj[15]!='--' else None,obj[16] if obj[16]!='--' else None,obj[17] if obj[17]!='--' else None,obj[18] if obj[18]!='--' else None,obj[19] if obj[19]!='--' else None,obj[20] if obj[20]!='--' else None,obj[21] if obj[21]!='--' else None,obj[22] if obj[22]!='--' else None,obj[23] if obj[23]!='--' else None])
```

A if function sees if last letter of the obj[0] is in the exception list or not and then returned to new_obj and finally appended to catalog.

Comment: It's very close what i want. So it helped a lot. I can do some modifications to do exact thing that i want. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help ! If you need any more support please reply.